# convert from `bufio.Reader` to `io.ReadWriteCloser`

Tags: go, io

I have an `io.ReadWriteCloser` in which I want to peek into it without advancing the reader,

so I am using

```
bi := bufio.NewReader(i)
bi.Peek(1)
```

So far so good, but later when I want to reuse the original `io.ReadWriteCloser` (`i`) it has only `EOF`.

So my question is how to convert back from `bufio.Reader` back to `io.ReadWriteCloser`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reuse the original strings.Reader in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154285/how-do-i-reuse-the-original-strings-reader-in-go)

Comment: Call `i.Seek(0, 0)` after `bi.Peek(1)`.

Comment: @SamHerrmann The types mentioned in the question do not have Seek method.

Comment: Right. Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) but it's tough to assist without having the broader context. If you need to peek into the `io.ReadWriteCloser` within a function, then perhaps the function argument type should be `io.ReadWriteSeeker` instead of `io.ReadWriteCloser`? Presumably the concrete type of your original reader does have a `Seek` method, but it's not available to you because it's being passed around as an `io.ReadWriteCloser`?

Comment: The original question why I need to `Peek()` into `io.ReadWriteCloser` was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465710/test-is-data-available-in-io-readwritecloser hopefully this adds more context to this question. So `Peek()` was just a way to achieve the wanted behavior and having both `Seek()/Peak()` was not the original intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the bufio.Reader buffers data from the underlying reader, the application must read from the bufio.Reader after the call to Peek.

To get an io.ReadWriteCloser that does this, wrap the bufio.Reader and the original io.ReadWriteCloser:

```
// BufferedReadWriteCloser has all of the methods
// from *bufio.Reader and io.ReadWriteCloser.
type BufferedReadWriteCloser struct {
    *bufio.Reader
    io.ReadWriteCloser
}

func (rw *BufferedReadWriteCloser) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return rw.Reader.Read(p)
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
rw := &BufferedReadWriteCloser{bufio.NewReader(i), i}
p, err := rw.Peek(1)
```

The value of `rw` satisfies the io.ReadWriteCloser interface.

There is no requirement or assumption that the io.ReadWriteCloser has a Seek method.

Comment: Neat solution! Create a hybrid of two types so the interface satisfies `io.ReadWriteCloser` while the most important `Read()` is now "redirected" to `bufio.Reader.Read()`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, you need access to the original reader's `Seek` method. This means that passing the reader around as an `io.ReadWriteCloser` is insufficient. Having said that, the following helper function may be a workaround:

```golang
func peek(r io.Reader, n int) ([]byte, error) {
    bi := bufio.NewReader(r)
    peeked, err := bi.Peek(n)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Use type assertion to check if r implements the 
    // io.Seeker interface. If it does, then use it to
    // reset the offset.
    if seeker, ok := r.(io.Seeker); ok {
        seeker.Seek(0, 0)
    }
    return peeked, nil
}
```

Now you can pass the `io.ReadWriteCloser` to this `peek` function. The `peek` function checks if the reader happens to implement the `Seek` method. If the `Seek` method is implemented, then `peek` will call it.

Comment: The other accepted answer solved my issue without a need to invoke `io.Seeker.Seek()`